# Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)

Tags: mac, ssl, certificate, openssl

I have a self-signed certification, I'm using it locally for my API. As you can see in the screenshot is working fine using Docker and Apache for the server side.

[image: SSL working fine]

The problem is when I tried to use the react App the request fails when I validate the certification using openssl command line, I got the error

```
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

I found some possible solutions but they suggest to use the fullchain which I don't have idea what they are talking about. I only have 2 files, cert and key

[image]

Would be amazing if someone can guide me in the right direction for fixing this annoying issue.

Thanks in advance, and let me know if can I provide with more insights.

Comment: Use certificate file also as CA certificate and you will get rid of this error.

Comment: Run `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <cert file>` and paste the output into your question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to verify a certificate, it must chain all the way to a trust-anchor. `openssl` checks this trust-anchor for a `keyUsage` extension. If present, it must contain `keyCertSign` as a minimum.  It turns out that if this extension exists but doesn't contain `keyCertSign` it will return error 21.

In addition, your client (`openssl s_client`) must know which certificate to use as a trust-anchor.  You configure `openssl` to use an additional trust-anchor with the `-CAfile` option, as follows:

`openssl s_client -CAfile <your cert file> -connect api.dev.thetripguru.com:443`

Comment: Hi, I got the same response than using without the cert file

Comment: I added the keyCertSign to the keyUsage extension, generated a new certificate, and I still got Error 21.  It turns out that my problem was using the Microsoft Windows 10 certificate installation wizard (I right-clicked the certificate and selected "Install certificate").  I let the wizard import the certificate to the area of the Certificate Store that it thought was appropriate.  It turned out that it imported the cert to the Intermediate Certs tab and NOT the Trusted Roots tab.  Once I placed the original cert  (WITHOUT keyCertSign) in the Trusted Roots tab everything worked perfectly !